# Is it possible to look up a facebook login associated with an application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-apps, app-id

I have a facebook application that we use however the log in to edit the permissions and admin for the application has been forgotten. Is there anyway I can use my app id to look up what log in information was used to create this application? Even the email address would be helpful.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

the application object should give you what is available.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/

Comment: sorry I misspoke, I meant the application object.
this is the graph explorer for the example given at the link I put in the answer
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=2439131959

Comment: bottom line, you will not be able to get much information on the application unless you can login with the account that owns it.  The information that is available, will be shown there.

Comment: dang yeah thats the problem no one can remember the login account that "owns" the app. We do know the app id though. Looks like I'm stuck.